# not able to get requirejs to work with mvc4

Tags: jquery, requirejs

i am trying to start with require js... and below is the most basic example i am trying to work with....

I have defiend "jquery" & "jqueryui" using require js and provided the dependency of jqueryui on jquery.....

as per the documentation.. below must work and i must get the jquit... but the alert box says that jqui is undefined....

what is wrong with my code??

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Configure the RequireJS paths to use an alias for the jQuery library.
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            "jquery": "./Scripts/jquery-1.8.2",
            "jqueryui": "./Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24"
        },
        shim: {
            "jqueryui": ["jquery"]
        }
    });
    // Now that we have configured a named alias for the jQuery library, 
    // let's try to load it using the named module.
    requirejs(["jquery", "jqueryui"], function(jq, jqui) {
        // Log the callback parameter.
        console.log("jq.fn.jquery:", jq.fn.jquery);
        alert(jqui);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically correct. However, you'll want to reference the ui plugin through the main jquery object. There is no separate UI 'module'. Thus:

```
requirejs(["jquery", "jqueryui"], function(jq) { // Note! one parameter
    // Log the callback parameter.
    console.log("jq.fn.jquery:", jq.fn.jquery);
    alert(jq.fn.button); // Note! The UI plugin is loaded!
});
```